# How can I read a custom key's value in Info.plist and use it in Xcode's build settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process, xcode5

I am attempting to read a custom info.plist key's value into a User Defined Build Setting.

The 'APP_VERSION' is a macro defined in my INFOPLIST_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS file.

What I am trying to accomplish is getting macro definitions from my INFOPLIST_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS file into build settings based on different configurations.

I am going about this the wrong way? Or am I just missing something.

[image: info.plist custom key]

[image: build settings]

Comment: What is your purpose behind "getting macro definitions from my INFOPLIST_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS file into build settings" ?

Comment: I am attempting to inject the builds version number into the Info.plist in order to use that as the Bundle Display Name.

I create archive builds of older iOS apps so I can keep them installed on devices for regression testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PlistBuddy` command in a 'Run Script Build Phase' to read and/or write values in your info.plist file.

To read:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print PRX_APP_VERSION' Info.plist
```

To write:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME NEW_VALUE" Info.plist
```

So in your Run Script Build Phase, read the value (or values) you want, store them into variables using standard shell scripting, modify as required, then write the values back to the new keys etc.